# Determine whether the sequence is uniformly convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Find out whether the following sequence is uniformly convergent on $E$.
>   $$
> f_n(x)=\ln\left(\sin x+\frac{1}{n}\right),\ \ x\in E=\left(0;\frac{\pi}{6}\right)
> $$

Here is what I did:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln\left(\sin x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln(\sin x)\\
&0<\sin x<\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
\right.\Rightarrow \ln(\sin x)\ \exists\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow f_n(x) \text{ converges to } f(x)=\ln(\sin x)\\
t_n=|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n\sin x}\right)\right|
$$
Then I thought that $$\forall n\ \ \exists x: t_n > 0.\ \ \text{Thus, }
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in E}t_n\ne0\Rightarrow f_n(x)\ \ \text{does not converge uniformly on E.}
$$
Is my solution correct? And if so, please, tell me how to properly prove that 
$\forall n\ \ \exists x:\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in E}t_n\ne0.$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If we take $x=\frac1{n^2}$ then $t_n$ is asymptotic with $\ln(1+n)$ which definitely doesn't go to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n\, \sin \frac{1}{n} = 1$.

Take $x_n = \frac{1}{n} \in (0,\pi/6)$ and find that as $n \to \infty$,

$$ \sup_{x \in (0,\pi/6)}|f_n(x) - f(x) | \geqslant \left|\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n\sin x_n}\right)\right| \to |\ln(2)| \neq 0$$